# Why does "Angular Material Tabs" active only the other one on Ionic 4?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, angular-material, ionic4, angular-activatedroute

I'm newbie with Ionic 4. I integrate [Angular Material](https://material.angular.io) into my Ionic 4 project. I have problem with [Angular Material - Tabs & Navigation](https://material.angular.io/components/tabs/overview#tabs-and-navigation). After I switch 2 tabs about 2 - 3 times, the tab just active the other one. I check HTML code, and I see problem in image below:

**When I reload App, It's still normal**
[image]

**After I switched 2 - 3 times,**
[image]

This is my project structure:

[image]

Please, see my code below:

**app-routing.module.ts**

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { PreloadAllModules, RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'home/tin-tuc',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
    path: 'home',
    loadChildren: './home/home.module#HomePageModule'
  },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { preloadingStrategy: PreloadAllModules }),
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

**app.component.html**

```html
<ion-app>
  <ion-router-outlet main></ion-router-outlet>
</ion-app>
```

**app.component.ts**

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import { Platform, MenuController } from '@ionic/angular';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen/ngx';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar/ngx';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: 'app.component.html'
})
export class AppComponent {

  constructor(
    private platform: Platform,
    private splashScreen: SplashScreen,
    private statusBar: StatusBar,
    private menuCtrl: MenuController,
  ) {
    this.initializeApp();
  }

  initializeApp() {
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
      this.statusBar.styleDefault();
      this.splashScreen.hide();
    });
  }
}
```

**app.module.ts**

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { RouteReuseStrategy, RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

import { IonicModule, IonicRouteStrategy } from '@ionic/angular';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen/ngx';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar/ngx';

//Angular Material
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  entryComponents: [],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(),
    AppRoutingModule,
    //Angular Material Component
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
  ],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    { provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**home.page.html**

*I call Angular Material Tabs in home.page.html*

```html
<ion-content>
  <nav mat-tab-nav-bar>
    <a mat-tab-link *ngFor="let link of navLinks" 
      [routerLink]="link.path" routerLinkActive #rla="routerLinkActive"
      [active]="rla.isActive">
      {{link.label}}
    </a>
  </nav>

  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</ion-content>
```

**home.page.ts**

*I set path and label name for a link*

```js
export class HomePage {
  navLinks = [
    { path: 'tin-tuc', label: 'TIN TỨC' },
    { path: 'nop-ho-so', label: 'NỘP HỒ SƠ' }
  ];
}
```

**home.module.ts**

*And i define my component 'tin-tuc' and 'nop-ho-so' and set path for them!*

```js
//Components
import { TinTucComponent } from '../components/tin-tuc/tin-tuc.component';
import { NopHoSoComponent } from '../components/nop-ho-so/nop-ho-so.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    ... //Some my other imported components

    RouterModule.forChild([
      {
        path: '',
        component: HomePage,
        children: [
          {
            path: 'tin-tuc',
            component: TinTucComponent
          },
          {
            path: 'nop-ho-so',
            component: NopHoSoComponent
          }
        ]
      },
    ]),
  ],

  declarations: [HomePage, TinTucComponent, NopHoSoComponent]
})
export class HomePageModule { }
```

Comment: where does the label `Page` and `Page1` come from? can you show your whole .html file?

Comment: @lan P Sorry, my mistake, it's the same label with **Image 1**. I edited! Thank you!

Comment: okay the shared codes are very insufficient and just adds more questions than clarity, so please share the whole ts and html code because the links could also be manipulated by something else in the ts file like a `@ViewChild` reference

Comment: @lan P Okay! I edited, I'm working around AppComponent and HomePage. So, other is default code of project when I created.